# UglifyJS: Минимизация js для одной папки

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

Поставил плагин UglifyJS в PhpStorm для минимизации js файлов. 
Всё работает, но как настроить работу плагина только для одного каталога?
Работаю с Node.js, поэтому мне нет нужды минимизировать серверные скрипты.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: а что такое UglifyJS плагин? Я не знаю таких плагинов для PHPStorm...

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете с nodejs, можете воспользоваться этим -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify